# Not able to change distributionUrl for Gradle

Tags: android, gradle, ionic3

I'm creating an Ionic App with Ionic 3 and I've integrated FCM plugin from [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/fcm/). And after that whenever I try to build a project, then it gives error

```
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.application']
Minimum supported Gradle version is 4.6. Current version is 4.1. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in Project_path\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-4.6-all.zip
```

So what I did is change the `distributionUrl` to `https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.6-all.zip` and build the project. After building the url automatically changes back to `https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip`.

What could be the solution or I'm heading in the wrong direction.